# How to add text to another layout without starting a new layout?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I know how we could use `Intent` and `#putExtra()` to send a text from an activity to the other, but the problem I am having is that whenever I do `startActivity(intent)`,  this starts a new `Layout` of the `Intent`, while I simply want to append text to the first layout I started with the intent, I don't want android to keep creating new layouts for every text I use `Intent` with. 
Basically I am trying to create an output log activity, where every new text will be appended in a new line in the layout program.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. First you need to learn the difference between a layout and an activity. Then you need to add relevant code to your question. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: I agree with @Kartik here. You seem to misunderstand how basic Android programming works, or you worded your question very poorly.

Comment: Yes I don't know Android programming very well, I am learning as I practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you keep starting new Intents with the same Activity, by default the OS will keep launching new instances of that Activity.  What I think you are asking for is to re-use the same activity and have the new intents be sent there.  This can be accomplished by utilizing [launch modes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#lmode).  Set your Activity's launch mode to singleTop in your manifest `android:launchMode="singleTop"`.  Then your activity will receive the new data in `onNewIntent()`.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    //Add new intent data to your layout
}
```

Comment: Yes I was precisely asking about that. Thank you so much for the quick help!